When I am training a neural network and I observe that the GPU utilization is at 0% while the CPU utilization is at 100%
When I am training a neural network and I observe that the GPU utilization is at 0% while the CPU utilization is at 100%

If I add 'to.device', I get the following error:

RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! (when checking argument for argument index in method wrapper_CUDA_gather)

My DQN model training code is as follows:
def train_dqn(dqn, target_dqn, optimizer, replay_buffer, num_episodes, batch_size, gamma,
              epsilon, epsilon_min,epsilon_decay, risk_coefficient_list, episode_rewards,     
              pbar,loss_list,resource_consumed_list):
    global resource_consumed, risk_coefficient
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = state_reset()
        done = False
        episode_reward = 0 
        scarce_list = []
        for i in range(len(state) - 1):
            scarce_list.append(state[i] * 0.8)
        while not done:
            actions = take_action(state, epsilon, dqn)
            next_state, done = environment_step(state, actions)
            reward, risk_coefficient, resource_consumed = get_reward(next_state, next_state, actions, scarce_list)
            replay_buffer.push(state, actions, reward, next_state, done)
            state = next_state
            episode_reward += reward
            if len(replay_buffer) > batch_size:
                states, actions, rewards, next_states, dones = replay_buffer.sample(batch_size)
                action_indices = torch.multinomial(actions, 1).squeeze(1).long() 
                current_q = dqn(states.float()).gather(1, action_indices.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)  
                next_q = target_dqn(next_states.float()).max(1)[0].detach()
                expected_q = rewards + gamma * next_q * (~dones)
                loss = nn.functional.mse_loss(current_q, expected_q.float()) 
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
            epsilon = max(epsilon_min, epsilon_decay * epsilon) 
        if episode % 10==0:
            target_dqn.load_state_dict(dqn.state_dict())


device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
dqn = DQN(state_size_dim, action_size_dim).to(device)
target_dqn = DQN(state_size_dim, action_size_dim).to(device)
target_dqn.load_state_dict(dqn.state_dict())
optimizer = optim.Adam(dqn.parameters())
with tqdm(total=int(num_episodes), desc=f'{algorithm_name.upper()} Iteration %d' % i) as pbar:
     train_dqn(dqn, target_dqn, optimizer, replay_buffer, num_episodes, batch_size,
                           gamma, epsilon, epsilon_min, epsilon_decay,
                           risk_coefficient_list,
                           episode_rewards, pbar, loss_list, resource_consumed_list)


That's because your dataset is still on the CPU.
You have two tensors on the same device and that's why your program works. If you move one to the GPU and you get RuntimeError about the tensors being on different devices, that means that your other tensor is still on the CPU.
Solution: Move your model and your dataset both on the same device.
